# Android - How can I load an image to a ImageView?

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to make a simple image viewing program, that just takes the images from a certain folder, and loads them from it.

I did some coding with less thinking, so I did stumble upon this:

```
Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    View rootView = (View)v.getParent();
    ImageView im = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //and here comes the problem...


   }
```

I have all my images from the folder loaded and have a collection, containg of all their absolute paths. Now, I want my imageView to switch its picture src with one from my collection. But how can I do that ?

Comment: Are images on a random folder inside the APK or on the sdcard?

Comment: Er...  does it matter? For the time being for my convenince they are in the package, but are NOT in /res/drawable. The image directory is registered as a resource in strings.xml and I could change it if I'd like to (or so I believe...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bitmaps. After reading the file from the absolute paths, convert to Bitmaps (see BitmapFactory) and apply the Bitmap to the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Collections Filled with Absolute Paths? I'd recommend you create an `int` Array of their Id's (`R.drawable.image01`) then use the `setImageResource(arr[3])` to set it...

But if you *have* to use the paths...then this [page](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/2/) might help...

Comment: Well, my idea is NOT to make an Id for every single file I'd like to have in my directory. Meaning - if I paste another 50 images in the folder, I don't want to have to register them as resourcer, or hardcode them in my application.